# Azure Devops External users with all permissions set as denied can still see Organization Settings

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created an external user in Azure DevOps (one with @outlook.com email). I have set this user as "Basic" with no access to any of the organization projects and I have also set all permissions to deny. Yet when he signs in, he is able to view organizations settings even though he cannot edit them. What am I doing wrong. The user should not be seeing anything.
How can I make this work?

Comment: Maybe you should try to set the user level as `Stakeholder` see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels)

Comment: @SomarZein still the same. Unbelievable. This is number one rule. You don't see anything you don't have access. I started wondering if Azure Dev Ops is a secure place to create your dev ops environment

Comment: did you check if user is in a group? Although I think that in general in Azure DevOps they don't deal with visibility as we used to see it in other apps and tool; It could be more like a Transparency thing :/  that is why the user can see almost every thing but can't edit a thing